# How do I customize fields of a Google Guice Injected Object?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, guice

I'm currently writing Integration tests, where I @Inject the "Store" object as a private field. However, by default the injected store has the "isShopifyInstalled" set to False, making my tests automatically fail. I need to be able to set "isShopifyInstalled" to true somehow, but can't seem to Mockito.mock + Inject the Store object. Any ideas on how to set this boolean to true when Guice Injecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your module does not explicitly bind Store, you can define a Module for the purposes of your tests that uses a @Provides method to provide configured "Store" objects. Use that module together with the "normal" modules in your test.